# How to decide initial parametervalues for curve fitting with lmfit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I'm currently working on a non-linear fit for several data coming from a DMA test (rheology).
For the data I'm currently working with, the program works BUT i want the program to be flexible in a way that the starting parameters for the curve fitting are dependent of the input of my data. Is there a way to determine this?

Maybe something with a Monte Carlo method, but I don't know where to start.

This is my code, thanks in advance! :

```
def calc_gmm(dframe):
    array_omega = np.array(dframe['Angular Frequency']).flatten()
    array_G_storage = np.array(dframe['Storage Modulus']).flatten()
    array_G_loss = np.array(dframe['Loss Modulus']).flatten()

    chisqr = 99999999999;
    j=1


    fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)


    while j <= 10:
        params = lmfit.Parameters()

        # Adding amount n of parameters and G0, start values were determined by trial and error
        params.add('n', value=j, vary=False, min=1, max=10)
        params.add('G0', value=0.4, min=0)
        for i in range(params['n'].value):
            params.add(f't_{i}', value=0.5, min=0)
            params.add(f'g_{i}', value=17, min=0)

        # Minimization function
        res = lmfit.minimize(min_function, params, args=(array_omega, array_G_storage, array_G_loss))

        # Determining the smallest chi-squared in order to develop a criterium to stop iterating over different orders
        if res.chisqr < chisqr*0.5:
            chisqr = res.chisqr
            ax1.plot(array_omega, array_G_storage + res.residual, label='n: '+ (str)(j))
            ax2.plot(array_omega, array_G_loss + res.residual, label='n: '+ (str)(j))
            j += 1
        else:
            params = lmfit.Parameters()
            j -= 1
            # Adding amount n of parameters and G0, start values were determined by trial and error
            params.add('n', value=j, vary=False, min=1, max=10)
            params.add('G0', value=0.4, min=0)
            for i in range(params['n'].value):
                params.add(f't_{i}', value=0.5, min=0)
                params.add(f'g_{i}', value=17, min=0)

            # Minimization function
            res = lmfit.minimize(min_function, params, args=(array_omega, array_G_storage, array_G_loss))

            j = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is "no" -- the proper range of parameter values will depend on what the objective function does with the parameters.  Like, just to be clear, it could first multiply all the 't_N' parameters by 1e-6.  The user needs to know what the function will do with the parameters.  Since you're really fitting experimental data you could (for example) just assert what the units of the parameters are.

But, if you have a stable function definition and some units or clear definitions for the parameters, you might be able to come up with a decent set of starting parameters.

For many of the model functions in lmfit (see https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/master/lmfit/models.py), we can make decent guesses for a set of data.  Like, for a peak-like function, you can say the centroid ought to be around the point of maximum intensity of the data, etc. Full-width at half-maximum can be found for a dataset without too much work, and then "sigma" is probably somewhere in the neighborhood of half of that.

Doing that for other functions will require some heuristics and common sense, but it should be doable.